Apache: another web server is already running
This question has been asked before, and I can solve it:
If you get the message 'Xampp: another web server is already running' you can run the command sudo netstat -nap | grep :80.
The result is this:
tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN     2109/apache2  
You need the number, in this case 2109. This number changes every time you try to start Xampp.
Run sudo kill 2109 and the process is stopped. Now you can safely start Xampp, all will be well.
Is there a way to make this change permanent? Every time I start Xampp that number changes. I know my solution is not permanent.

Do you have Apache set up to start automatically on boot? Do you get any output for systemctl status apache2.service?

If so, sudo systemctl disable apache2.service, as you don't really need Apache to start automatically on boot since you're starting XAMPP manually.
